# invoke a java app from shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar

I'm trying to invoke a java jar from a shell script. It works with a windown batch script. I tried to translate this working batch script into a shell script but don't get it working. Where is the bug?

The original batch file (works perfectly):

```
@echo off
rem set the right host here
set host=example.com
set port=8080
set urlPartBeforeApiVersion=/project/api
rem geographical region
set west=47.358352
set south=8.493598
set east=47.406704
set north=8.560889
set numberOfVehicles=10
set idPerfix=SIM_KSDN128D
set vehicleSpeed=40
set gpsSendInterval=10
set cloudmadeApiKey=kldhfjsghjf83hf83hf83hf89whs89
java -jar %~p0dist/application.jar %host% %port% %west% %south% %east% %north% %numberOfVehicles% %idPerfix% %vehicleSpeed% %gpsSendInterval% %urlPartBeforeApiVersion% %cloudmadeApiKey%
pause
```

The shell script (doesn't work):

```
#!/bin/sh
host="example.com"
port="8080"
urlPartBeforeApiVersion="/project/api"
west="47.358352"
south="8.493598"
east="47.406704"
north="8.560889"
numberOfVehicles="10"
idPerfix="SIM_KSDN128D"
vehicleSpeed="40"
gpsSendInterval="10"
cloudmadeApiKey="kldhfjsghjf83hf83hf83hf89whs89"
java -jar $(dirname $0)/dist/application.jar $host $port $west $south $east $north $numberOfVehicles $idPerfix $vehicleSpeed $gpsSendInterval $urlPartBeforeApiVersion $cloudmadeApiKey
```

The application throws a Java NumberFormatException and exits. I tested the script on cygwin on Windows 7 and on centos.

Comment: paste full stacktrace, you are passing something wrong that app isn't expecting

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: "xception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at application.Application.main(Application.java:36)

Comment: Is the value you are that you parsing to `int` represented by one of the parameters you're passing at the command line?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is the port="8080". That's what is sais in the stack trace.

Comment: Can you show the code where you parse the arguments? In particular where you parse "port".

Comment: Can you change #!/bin/sh to #/bin/bash and retry? Also, try putting echo before java temporarily to see what's being actually passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many wonderful things that can happen when your bash script has DOS line separators.

Run your script through `dos2unix`, `sed -i 's/\r//'`, `tr -d '\r'` or whatever you have available, and try again.

For future reference, whenever you see that a line starts with garbage and is surreptitiously truncated, such as

```
"xception [...]: For input string: "8080
```

rather than

```
Exception [...]: For input string: "8080"
```

You know that you're dealing with carriage returns.